# Nuxt vuejs Splide is not scrolling

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, splidejs

Personalization
                            
                                Techrevolve UX offers a suite of cutting-edge features designed to streamline your user
                                research process.

```
                    </div>
                    <div class="px-6 mt-7 lg:mb-[85px]">
                        <img src="@/assets/bb.png" alt="" class="w-full object-cover">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </SplideSlide>
               


                <SplideSlide>
                    <div class="block max-w-[561px]  mr-4 mb-2 mx-auto bg-[#F9F9F9] rounded-lg lg:rounded-[50px] h-[280px] lg:h-[554px] shadow">
                        <div class="p-6 lg:pt-16 lg:px-8">
                            <h5 class="mb-4 text-lg lg:text-[32px] font-semibold tracking-tight text-gray-900">
                                Testing and Feedback</h5>
                            <p class="font-normal text-xs leading-relaxed lg:w-[498px] lg:text-xl">
                                From seamless tester matching to in-depth feedback analysis, prepare to transform your product insights.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div class=" px-6 mt-7 lg:mb-[85px]">
                            <img src="@/assets/bb.png" alt="" class="w-full object-cover">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </SplideSlide>


                <SplideSlide>
                    <div class="block max-w-[561px]  mr-4 mb-2 mx-auto bg-[#F9F9F9] rounded-lg lg:rounded-[50px] h-[280px] lg:h-[554px] shadow">
                        <div class="p-6 lg:pt-16 lg:px-8">
                            <h5 class="mb-4 text-lg lg:text-[32px] font-semibold tracking-tight text-gray-900">
                                Analytics</h5>
                            <p class="font-normal text-xs leading-relaxed lg:w-[498px] lg:text-xl">
                                Techrevolve UX offers your product insights and in-depth analysis like no other.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="px-6 mt-7">
                            <img src="@/assets/aa.png" alt="" class="w-full object-cover bg-[#F9F9F9]">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </SplideSlide>

                </div>
            </Splide>
        </div>
```

const straightCarouselOptions = {
rewind: true,
wheel: false,
autoplay: true,
type: 'slide',
perPage: 3,
arrows: false,
pagination: false,
}

Comment: Try properly defining your issue, are there any errors in the console or terminal? Also paste your entire code related to the issue, the above code starts on a closing `</div>` element which isn't ideal for reproducing the issue.